# Proper way to bind an object's method to an event

Tags: jquery, this, jquery-events

Is this the way to properly bind and event to an object's method in JavaScript using jQuery?

I've set up a little example code but the part I'm concerned of is the two-lines after the comment "*is this ok?*"

Of course, as the callback is a method of the object, I need the *context* to remain the same.

```
function MyPrototype(id) {

    this.id = id;
    this.sel = '#' + id;

    // *** IS THIS OK? ***
    $(this.sel).on('click', function(evt) {
        MyPrototype.prototype.mouseClick.call(this, evt); });
}

MyPrototype.prototype.mouseClick = function (evt) {

    // I want to use evt to get info about the event
    // I want use this to access properties and methods of the instance

    alert(this.id + ' was clicked');
}

myObject1 = new MyPrototype('myDiv1');
myObject2 = new MyPrototype('myDiv2');
```

Also, I may come to the necessity of unbinding the event from the specific function.

But the following is not working...

```
MyPrototype.prototype.unbindClick = function() {

    $(this.sel).off('click', function(evt) {
        MyPrototype.prototype.mouseClick.call(this, evt); });
}

myObject2.unbindClick();
```

Note that I'm passing an inline function as the event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
function MyPrototype(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.sel = '#' + id;

    // using jQuery.proxy:
    $(this.sel).on('click', $.proxy(this.mouseClick, this));

    // or Function.bind:
    // $(this.sel).on('click', this.mouseClick.bind(this));

    // or writing it out:
    /*
    var self = this;
    $(this.sel).on('click', function () {
      return self.mouseClick.apply(self, arguments);
    });
    */
}

MyPrototype.prototype.mouseClick = function(evt) {

    // I want to use evt to get info about the event
    // I want use this to access properties and methods of the instance

    console.log(this.id + ' was clicked');
};

var myObject1 = new MyPrototype('myDiv1');
var myObject2 = new MyPrototype('myDiv2');
```

http://jsbin.com/axokuz/1/

---

**About the update to the question**:

If you want to unbind a single event handler you would need the exact same handler function used while binding. Otherwise the whole event would be unbound. Neither the solution you added to the question nor `$.proxy` would help with that. There are some solutions, though:

- keep a reference to the bound handler and use that while unbinding
- use [jQuery's Namespaced Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events)

Comment: Thank for your reply, but... aren't the "call" approach and "$.proxy" approach equivalent? Or there is some reason I should always (or in some cases) use the jQuery's proxy?

Comment: `$.proxy` is just a shim for [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). It's really just a matter of taste whether to allways *write out* the `.call` construct or use this kind of helper. As you're using jQuery anyway, this is probably the quickest way to do it cross-browser.

Comment: @Paolo I added an alternative as a code-comment, have a look.

Comment: Yoshi, I've edited my question. The solution you proposed seem to be an answer to the second question I've added lately too. But it seem also that using jQuery's "off" with the function returned by "proxy" will unbind that function from every object. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to unbind the specific handler, from the specific element for the specific event the jQuery's proxy object must be saved into a property of the object to be accessed at *unbind* time.

Like this

```
function MyPrototype(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.sel = '#' + id;
    this.handler = $.proxy(this.mouseClick, this);

    $(this.sel).on('click', this.handler);
};

MyPrototype.prototype.mouseClick = function(evt) {

    console.log(this.id + ' was clicked');
};

MyPrototype.prototype.unbindClick = function() {

    $(this.sel).off('click', this.handler);
};
```